# PowerShell: Преобразование строковой переменной в переменную типа "Директория"

Tags: powershell

Пытаюсь автоматизировать установку прав доступа на папку через PowerShell. Насколько я понимаю - мне необходимо преобразовать вводимую переменную из строкового типа в тип "Директория", чтобы cmd-лет смог его воспринять. Ниже приведён код, но он не работает

```
$my_login = "SomeDomain\SomeUser"
$enter_path = Read-Host "На какую папку расширяем права?"
$path = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$enter_path
$acl = Get-ACL -Path $path
$Rule=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $my_login,"FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","InheritOnly","allow"
$acl.AddAccessRule($Rule)
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl
```

Comment: Интересная формулировка "Не работает". Может какой то вывод там есть?

Comment: Не работает в том плане, что пользователя добавляет, а права нет. Ошибок не выдаёт.

Comment: Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl -ErrorVariable ACLError -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' попробуйте. Потом выведете ошибку из переменной ACLError

Comment: К сожалению ничего: http://i65.tinypic.com/29e2eeb.png

Comment: @anderson а с чего вы решили, что права не выдаются? Только что проверил ваш код, права выдались. Идем на вкладку "Безопасность" => Выбираем интересующего нас пользователя =>  Видим галочку на поле "Особые разрешения" => жмем "Дополнительно" и видим "Полный доступ". Ну или проще, Get-Acl $path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$acl = Get-ACL -Path $(get-item $path)
```

Но вообще и ваш вариант должен работать, может что-то не то вводите в $path